# tailwind css not working between components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I have created a button component where i have passed props for how the btn will look. But when i try to use the props the props dont work. I dont think this is a problem with my code because if you use the colors manually first in the btn file, compile it, then use them as a prop it works only for that color

src/Button.js

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ text, img, textColor, bg, hoverBg }) {
  console.log(hoverBg);
  return (
    <button
      className={`flex-center h-10 w-full ring-1 ring-gray-300 rounded-full bg-${bg} hover:bg-${hoverBg}`}
    >
      <img src={img} alt="button-img" className="h-6" />
      <h1 className={`font-bold text-${textColor}`}>{text}</h1>
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

src/pages/Register.page.js (The page where im using the button comp)

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ text, img, textColor, bg, hoverBg }) {
  console.log(hoverBg);
  return (
    <button
      className={`flex-center h-10 w-full ring-1 ring-gray-300 rounded-full bg-${bg} hover:bg-${hoverBg}`}
    >
      <img src={img} alt="button-img" className="h-6" />
      <h1 className={`font-bold text-${textColor}`}>{text}</h1>
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamic class names in tailwind https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: oh ok sorry i did not know about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class… text-${textColor} as a string.

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

You have to return the complete string instead of only color from the props. Like in your props if `textColor` is returning `red-600` then you have to make it to return the string like `text-red-600`.

Further you can see my answer here [How to dynamically populate tailwindcss grid-cols-x property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260485/how-to-dynamically-populate-tailwindcss-grid-cols-x-property/72268889#72268889)

Answer (score 0):

It is working with style:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: classBackgroundImage}}>
      </div>
```