# How to pass a dynamic arbitrary value to a JSX Element using Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and I'm trying to build a component that looks like [the graph in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5omWV.png).

To do so, I have an array of spending objects in JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "day": "mon",
    "amount": 17.45
  },
  {
    "day": "tue",
    "amount": 34.91
  },
  {
    "day": "wed",
    "amount": 52.36
  },
  {
    "day": "thu",
    "amount": 31.07
  },
  {
    "day": "fri",
    "amount": 23.39
  },
  {
    "day": "sat",
    "amount": 43.28
  },
  {
    "day": "sun",
    "amount": 25.48
  }
]
```

However when I try to iterate over this array and create a div with a height proportional to the amount in the JSON file, the div isn't displayed. When I check devtools, I have the correct className for the element : `<div class="bg-red w-8 h-[35px] rounded"></div>`

Here is my React/Tailwind code :

```js
const Spendings = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2.5">
      {spendings.map((spending) => {
        let height = Math.round(spending.amount * 2);
        return (
          <div key={spending.day}>
            <div className={`bg-red w-8 h-[${height}px] rounded`}></div>
            <p className="text-brown-300 text-sm">{spending.day}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried setting a hard-coded value such as `h-[35px]` and it works.
I also tried setting this dynamic value through inline styling:

```js
const Spendings = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2.5">
      {spendings.map((spending) => {
        return (
          <div key={spending.day}>
            <div
              className={`bg-red w-8 rounded`}
              style={{ height: spending.amount * 2 }}
            ></div>
            <p className="text-brown-300 text-sm">{spending.day}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And it works: [Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpK4z.png)
(I know, styling is not done.)

Did I miss something here ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dynamic position values in Tailwind CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560190/using-dynamic-position-values-in-tailwind-css)

Comment: For more information about dynamically-generated classes, see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: Yes I found this page in the doc yesterday. It answers my question thank you.
I don't know stack overflow very well but it seems I can't upvote your answer because it's a comment (and not an answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use style for dynamically change values. For example:

```
style={{width: percent + '%'}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Tailwind has its complication reading variables inside classnames. In this case you have two options:

- Use JIT in your tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

For more detail, Please check this docs.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

- Modify the variable to be accesible for tailwind

```
const Spendings = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2.5">
      {spendings.map((spending) => {
        let height =  `w-[${Math.round(spending.amount * 2)}px]`
        return (
          <div key={spending.day}>
            <div className={`bg-red w-8 ${height} rounded`}></div>
            <p className="text-brown-300 text-sm">{spending.day}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Tailwind 3.0+ always uses the JIT mode. Also, your solution is still dynamically creating the class contained in your `height` variable, so it will not be parsed by Tailwind.