# Dynamic colors in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

Is it possible to make the color dynamic in tailwind config.

I want to received the desired color for (primary , accent) from **backend via api**.

So the user can change the color from the admin panel.

**i want to get this hex value from api**
[image: i want to get this hex from api]

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300855/load-colors-for-tailwind-config-js-from-server-database-by-using-php) can help? Depends on what comes from backend - object with keys (like color palette) or every single color

Answer (score 7):

You can try fetching the [CSS variables](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables) to change you color palette without changing `tailwind.config.js`

config file:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary": {
            100:"var(--primary-color-100)",
            200:"var(--primary-color-200)",
           },
        "accent": "var(--accent-color)"
      },
    },
  },
};
```

css file:

```
:root {
  --primary-color-100: #fff;
  --primary-color-200: #fff00;
  --accent-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible but instead of only `primary`, you need to return the complete string like `bg-primary`(as tailwind only recognises the string) where your `primary` color should be defined in `tailwind.config.js` file.

For an example you can refer to my answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260485/how-to-dynamically-populate-tailwindcss-grid-cols-x-property/72268889#72268889) question.

Comment: I dont understand your answer actually so I updated the question

Comment: What I want to say that you have to give `complete value as string` where you apply. For `complete,` I mean to say that if you are changing background then you have to return `bg-primary-200`

Answer (score 0):

If you think that in your application it is possible to get just the name of a predefined color palette instead of getting all CSS variables, you can try this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors

This automates the creation of CSS variables according to the current theme and also gives the names of the colors you want in the tailwind, always updated with the current theme. But I don't know if you can define a new palette at runtime.